# Using C++ Map in Cython

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, cython, stdmap

I am trying to use map from C++ in my Cython code (essentially as a means to replace Python dictionary). Here my code:

parameters.pyx file

```
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string  cimport string

cdef class Parameters:
    cdef map data[string,int]

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {{'a', 1}}

    cpdef void change_data(self, dict newdata):
        self.data = newdata
```

model.pyx file

```
from parameters import Parameters
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string  cimport string

cpdef single_run():
    parameters = Parameters()

    cdef map newMap[string,int]
    
    newMap ={{'a',2}}

    parameters.change_data(newMap)
```

Error:
File "parameters.pyx", line 9, in parameters.Parameters.**init**
self.data = {{'a', 1}}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Here is the setup.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(["*.py","*.pyx"],
language="c++")
    
)
```

Comment: Cython doesn't understand the "new" C++ initializer list syntax. You'll either need to explicitly insert the initial entries or move the fancier parts to a .h and/or .cpp file that your .pyx file references.